# Rails Receives Repetitive Requests on One Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My route is as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'courses' => 'application#index'
  get 'check_db' => 'application#check_db'

  root 'application#index'
end
```

And my `application#check_db` is

```
def check_db
  p "test"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

When I visit `/check_db` on my browswer (tried both in Chrome and Safari), if working properly, it should `GET "/check_db"` and then `GET "/"`. But actually, the log shows that there are four requests, with the above pattern repeated twice (i.e. `GET "/check_db"`, `GET "/"`, `GET "/check_db"`, `GET "/"`). There is absolutely no code in my `application#index` that does any other redirection. So why is this?

The situation described above happen most of the times. However, occasionally, it works as expected. I did not change the code in the interim.

If it is in interest, the entire log is pasted below:

```
Started GET "/check_db" for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:05:06 -0800
Processing by ApplicationController#check_db as HTML
"test"
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:05:06 -0800
Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
  Rendering application/index.html.erb within layouts/application
[MongoDB query log]
  Rendered application/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 16.4ms)


Started GET "/check_db" for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:05:07 -0800
Processing by ApplicationController#check_db as HTML
"test"
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 8ms


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:05:07 -0800
Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
  Rendering application/index.html.erb within layouts/application
[MongoDB query log]
  Rendered application/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 15.0ms)
```

Comment: That's really weird dude, is this the only action you have this issue? It's also very weird to have an index action on the ApplicationController itself, you shouldn't do that unless is a very special situation.

Comment: I also have a `/update_db` URL action which is routed to `application#update_db`. But the code does not relate to `check_db` in any way, besides that both of them `redirect_to root_path` at the end.

Comment: Does it perform only one request if you visit the index action directly?

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo yes it does

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo after repeating it several times. I find this to be an occasional behavior. Sometimes it shows two requests as expected, but sometimes there are four.